# Hibernate can't load class when packaged, but can in IDE

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, intellij-idea

When I run my program in Intellij, it works fine. Maven will package it perfectly happily, and it will launch fine, but as soon as I try to retrieve anything from the database with hibernate, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at Program.GUI.GUITools.SavableSelector.initialGetElements(SavableSelector.java:112)
        at Program.GUI.GUITools.SelectorPanel.initialise(SelectorPanel.java:57)
        at Program.GUI.GUITools.SavableSelector.initialise(SavableSelector.java:32)
        at Program.GUI.GUITools.SavableSelector.<init>(SavableSelector.java:21)
        at Program.GUI.GUITools.SavableSelector.getSelectionFromUser(SavableSelector.java:26)
        at Program.GUI.TopFrame$1.actionPerformed(TopFrame.java:33)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jpa.converter.ContextDataJsonAttributeConverter]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:351)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.applyScanResultsToManagedResources(ScanningCoordinator.java:235)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.coordinateScan(ScanningCoordinator.java:81)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:98)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:228)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:170)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:76)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:181)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:129)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:71)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:52)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
        at Program.Database.Controller.<clinit>(Controller.java:15)
        ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jpa.converter.ContextDataJsonAttributeConverter.<clinit>(ContextDataJsonAttributeConverter.java:47)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:345)
        ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 60 more
```

My problem seems almost identical to [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40309040/different-behavior-for-class-loading-in-ide-and-jar-file), but there was no answer to that question, and that was literally the one thing that came up when i googled the error. I have the same answers as he did for the questions asked on that post.

This part `Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jpa.converter.ContextDataJsonAttributeConverter]`

Seems like the relevant part - and the program will run and hibernate doesn't complain if I remove the log4j dependencies from my pom file - though the logging does complain obviously.

I have included my pom file:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>Program.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.193</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.intellij/annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intellij</groupId>
        <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
        <version>12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jdatepicker/jdatepicker -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jdatepicker</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdatepicker</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.miglayout/miglayout -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.miglayout</groupId>
        <artifactId>miglayout</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jfree/jfreechart -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-csv -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

To be clear, i'm removing the following dependencies to have it work:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Hopefully you can help - I'm at a complete loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class that is not found is jackson `ObjectMapper`. In the pom for `log4j-core` (v 2.7), this can be found:

```
<!-- Required for JSON support -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<!-- Required for JSON support -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

The optional flag means that these are not included as transitive dependencies. Add them to your pom (optional flag not needed), and it should work.

As to why it works in IDEA, it might be that the dependency is included in some other module (IDEA projects has 1 flattened classpath, built files have one each.) Or, some config is different so that json support is not required when running from IDEA.

Comment: Thank you, that sorted it! I'm incredibly grateful